# why $B_x= \{\{x\}\}$ is a countable local basis at $x$?

Tags: general-topology

Here is the pdf link :http://eacharya.inflibnet.ac.in/data-server/eacharya-documents/55dabe0ae41301ad652caf1f_INFIEP_212/2303/ET/212-2303-ET-V1-S1__chapter5.pdf

i have  some doubt in first  countable definition , my doubt marked  in red line given below

[image]

**My doubts** : Here $X$  is uncountable  ,$ x\in X$ , then why $B_x= \{\{x\}\}$  is a  countable local basis at $x$ ?

I think its  should  be uncountable local basis  since $X$  is uncountable

Comment: Countable local basis means the *local* basis is countable. In other words, the set $\{\{x\}\}$ is countable.

Comment: .@ElliotG im not getting why set $\{\{x\}\} $is countable? ....if i  take  $x \in \mathbb{R}  $,then it will uncountable since $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable

Comment: $\{\{x\}\}$ is a set with one element — namely $\{x\}$. It is a finite set, and thus countable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{\{x\}\}$ is a set with **one** element namely the open set $\{x\}$. And so this set is surely countable ( finite sets are countable too; in this definition and others like it, countable is to be read as “ at most countable”).

And as for *each point separately* we have a countable local base *at that point*, the space is first countable. ( it does not matter there that we uncountably many such local bases, one for each point).

And as to the final argument, we see that if $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for $X$, for all $x \in X$, $\{x\} \in \mathcal{B}$ is forced, as in the quoted argument. So $x \to \{x\}$ is an injection of the uncountable $X$ into $\mathcal{B}$ giving a more direct argument that *every base* is uncountable, so $X$ is not second countable.